# Usage of global variables and local variables in different subs

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm copy pasting stuff from Excel to PowerPoint using VBA. It's working, but I need to clean up my code. The problem is I have no clue what is good practice when it comes to variables (or objects) that are used in more than one procedure. I think I lack some fundamental understanding in this regard.

1. When passing a variable from one procedure to another, is it a bad idea  to use the same name in both procedures? So for example

   ```
   Sub 1()
       Dim a As Long, b As Long
       Call Sub2(a, b)
       '...
   End Sub

   Sub2(a As Long, b As Long)
       '...
   End Sub
   ```

   Should `Sub2` call the variables differently, for example x and y? If not, I'm coming back to question 1): What's the reason to pass these variables directly from `Sub1` to `Sub2` and not declare them globally? I get it when I intend to use the original value of `a` and `b` in `Sub1` after calling `Sub2` (so basically pass it as `ByVal` to `Sub2`), but in my situation that's not the case.
2. Is there a reason to limit the usage of global variables? I left them in my code as local, but should I define `lRowAn`, `lRowData` etc. globally?
3. When should I pass a variable from a sub to another? In my code below, to do this with `iSlides` makes sense to me, but not for `wsEm`.

   The following is part of my actual code. The Subs `EmData` and `EmDataAn` are very similar and I'll see if I can merge them, but they illustrate very well the issue I have because they use many of the same variables.

   ```
   Public mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide
   Public PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
   Public myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
   Public MonatNum As String, JahrNum As String, MonatStr As String

   Sub CreateReport()    
       Dim DestinationPPT As String
       Dim iSlides As Integer
       Dim fRowAn As Long, lRowAn As Long, lRowData As Long
       Dim wbEm As Workbook
       Dim wsEm As Worksheet

       Set PowerPointApp = New PowerPoint.Application
       DestinationPPT = "C:\VBA\ReportTemplate.pptm"
       Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)

       Set wbEm = Workbooks.Open("C:\VBA\Report.xlsx")
       Set wsEm = wbEm.Sheets("Sheet1")

       lRowAn = wsEm.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
       fRowAn = wsEm.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row + 1

       If lRowAn >= 127 Then
           If lRowData <= 127 Then '4 Slides, but separate Annotations from Data
               iSlides = 1
               Call EmData(wsEm, iSlides)
               Call EmDataAn(wsEm, iSlides)
           Else '4 Slides
               iSlides = 3
               Call EmData(wsEm, iSlides)
           End If
       Else '3 Slides
           Call EmData(wsEm, iSlides)
       End If

       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       wbEm.Close SaveChanges:=False
       Application.DisplayAlerts = True

       PowerPointApp.Visible = True
       PowerPointApp.Activate
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
   End Sub



   Sub EmData(wsEm As Worksheet, iSlides As Integer)
       Dim i As Integer
       Dim fRowDataCalc As Long, lRowDataCalc As Long, lRowCopy As Long
       Dim rowHght As Long
       Dim rng As Range

       For i = 0 To iSlides
           fRowDataCalc = 4 + 40 * i + i * 1
           lRowDataCalc = 4 + 40 * (i + 1) + i * 1

           With wsEm
               .Range("B2:K3").Copy .Range("B500")
               .Range("B" & fRowDataCalc & ":K" & lRowDataCalc).Copy .Range("B502")
               rowHght = .Range("B3").EntireRow.Height
               .Range("B501").RowHeight = rowHght
               lRowCopy = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
               Set rng = .Range("B500:K" & lRowCopy)
           End With

           Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.AddSlide(myPresentation.Slides.Count + 1, PPLayout("LayoutEmittenten"))
           mySlide.Shapes.Placeholders(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Headline (" & i + 1 & ")"
           Call PasteEm(mySlide, rng)
           rng.Clear
       Next i

   End Sub

   Sub EmDataAn(wsEm As Worksheet, iSlides As Integer)
       Dim lRowAn As Long, fRowAn As Long, lRowData As Long, fRowDataCalc As Long, lRowDataCalc As Long
       Dim rng As Range
       Dim rowHght As Long, lRowCopy As Long

       lRowAn = wsEm.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
       fRowAn = wsEm.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row - 1
       lRowData = wsEm.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

       iSlides = iSlides + 1
       fRowDataCalc = 4 + 40 * iSlides + iSlides * 1
       lRowDataCalc = lRowData

       'Last sheet with data
       With wsEm
           .Range("B2:K3").Copy .Range("B500")
           .Range("B" & fRowDataCalc & ":K" & lRowDataCalc).Copy .Range("B502")
           rowHght = .Range("B3").EntireRow.Height
           .Range("B501").RowHeight = rowHght
           lRowCopy = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
           Set rng = .Range("B500:K" & lRowCopy)
       End With

       Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.AddSlide(myPresentation.Slides.Count + 1, PPLayout("LayoutEmittenten"))

       mySlide.Shapes.Placeholders(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Headline (" & iSlides + 2 & ")"
       Call PasteEm(mySlide, rng)
       rng.Clear
       'Annotations
       Set rng = wsEm.Range("B" & fRowAn & ":K" & lRowAn)
       rng.Copy
       Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.AddSlide(myPresentation.Slides.Count + 1, PPLayout("LayoutEmittenten"))
       mySlide.Shapes.Placeholders(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Headline (" & iSlides + 2 & ")"
       Call PasteEm(mySlide, rng)
   End Sub



   Sub PasteEm(mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide, rng As Range)
       Dim myShape As PowerPoint.Shape

       rng.Copy
       DoEvents
       mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile ' = 2
       Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
       With myShape
           .Width = 683
           .Top = 70
           .Left = 5
       End With
   End Sub
   ```

This is not so much about code functionality, but how to use variables in general.

Comment: Variables are searched for in local scope first so passing them between subs I think may be considered more efficient. It is also a nice tidy way to see what variables are having their values used or modified within receiving subs/functions. Global can be useful if a variable is used in lots of places but I generally avoid if possible.

Comment: @QHarr So if we take `lRowAn`. I use it in the procedures `CreateReport` and `EmDataAn`. In both I declare it locally calculate it the same way - I should change that to passing it from `CreateReport` and `EmDataAn`, right? Because there's no reason to do something twice if I can just do it once and then pass it on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Local Variable

First of all declare every variable as local as possible. Eg if it is needed in only one procedure/function declare it there.

#### Local Variable (Passed as Parameter)

If you need to access a variabe in more than one procedure/function then it is a good idea to pass it to the next function as a parameter. This can be done `ByRef` (which is default) or `ByVal`.

```
Sub ProcedureA()
    Dim ParamA As String
    ParamA = "AAA"
    Dim ParamB As String
    ParamB = "BBB"

    ProcedureB ParamA, ParamB

    Debug.Print ParamA 'returns 111
    Debug.Print ParamB 'returns BBB
End Sub

Sub ProcedureB(ByRef Param1 As String, ByVal Param2 As String)
    Param1 = "111" 'this will change ParamA in ProcedureA too
    Param2 = "222" 'this value will only be changed in ProcedureB
End Sub
```

While using `ByRef` (by reference) makes it possible to change the parameter in `ProcedureB` and have it also changed in `ProcedureA`, but the parameter that is passed `ByVal` (by value) does not change in `ProcedureA`.

Here it technically doesn't make any difference if you name the variables differently or use the same name. Use the name that is most meaningful in each of the procedures would be a good practice (see headline variable names below).

Actually I think it is also a good practice to always specify if it is `ByRef` or `ByVal` and not use the default. When using the default you always have to remember that it is `ByRef` by default in VBA but in VB.NET the default is `ByVal` which can easily get confusing (at least me).

After `ProcedureA` ends the variables are not available anymore (data is lost).

#### Global Variable

If you want the data to be persistant and accessible in more than one function then use global variabes (use them as rarely as possible).

```
Dim GlobalVarA As String

Sub ProcedureA()
    GlobalVarA = "AAA"
End Sub

Sub ProcedureB()
    Debug.Print GlobalVarA 'return AAA (if ProcedureA was run before)
End Sub
```

Note that in this case **any** procedure can change the value of `GlobalVarA`. If you pass it as a parameter as explained above, then only the procedures that the variable is passed to can access the variable.

Global variables will lose their data when Excel VBA ends (or file gets closed).

A down side of using global variables in a procedure is, you need always to check its value before using it the first time. Because if it was not initialized yet it is `Empty` or `Nothing`. For example (above) when running `ProcedureB` you cannot rely on that `ProcedureA` was already run before. So you would need to check the value of `GlobalVarA` before using it in `ProcedureB` especially if it is an object you have to test if for not beeing `Nothing` or you will easily run into errors.

#### Local vs. Global

So we can summarize, that restricting the access to a variable as much as possible makes your code more secure and more reliable (no other function can accidentally change it if it is only declared locally). Only use global variables if you really need to.

#### Re-Use Variable names

To re-use variable names is no problem in general if they are declared locally. But it gets tricky if you use the same name for a global and local variable (then VBA prefers the local one!)

```
Dim VarA As String 'global

Sub ProcedureA()
    Dim VarA As String 'same name local
    VarA = "AAA" 'this uses always the local variable!
End Sub

Sub ProcedureB()
    Debug.Print VarA 'this uses the global variable and it is empty (after ProcedureA is run) 
End Sub
```

In general it is a very good practice to use meaningful variable names only. That means instead of calling a variable `rng1` and `rng2` call them for example `InputRange` and `OutputRange`. Also if you need a counter (to eg loop through rows and columns) often `i` and `j` are used, but it is much more readable if you use eg `iRow` and `iCol` as variable names.

#### Option Explicit

In order to force a proper variable declaration I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*. This prevents you from mis-typing variable names and accidentally introduce new variables.

Comment: Thank you. "Only use global variables if you really need to." - well, when do I need it? Take `wsEm`for instance: I use it in `CreateReport`, `EmData` and `EmDataAn`and pass it from the first procedure to the other two. Is this ok or can I declare it globally?

Comment: I would prefer to pass it as a parameter, because declaring it gobally you would need to handle what I described in "Global Variable" as down-side effect (see my edited answer above).

Comment: If I may add something, when dealing with worksheets I feel more efficient to declare them global and write a little code to set them all. So the first thing in any "initial" procedures is calling that setting and then you can forget about that. It saves a lot of writting when you need to work multiple sheets on multiple procedures.

Comment: @Damian I don't think that this is a good practice. First because you cannot forget about it because if your code ends like by using the `End` statement or pressing the stop macro button twice then you end up with not initialized variables. The only way to prevent this is to check for initialization in *each* procedure. And secondly you could just use the VBA name of the worksheets (that you can change in the project explorer in VBE) because that is exactly the same and already declared automatically. So no need to declare global variables for the worksheets again.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ wouldn't the whole procedure end when doing what you are saying? So you should start all over again and so would the code to set the sheets. Also, using sheet variables is for writting more clearer, right? Otherwise none would declare sheets, just do as you stated.  Genuine question.

Comment: @Damian note that there are 2 different sheet naming systems (at the same time). The visible tab name `Worksheets("Sheet1")` and the VBA name `Sheet1`. The VBA name behaves exactly like you did `Set Sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")`, so instead of declaring a new global variable you can just edit the VBA name `Sheet1` to something like `ReportSheet`. Using VBA names ensures that always the correct sheet is addressed while using `Worksheets("Sheet1")` uses whatever sheet is named `Sheet1` by a user. In general VBA names are more reliable and the preferable way to go.

Comment: I see, that's something new I've learn today. Will give it a try, Thanks @Pᴇʜ!

Comment: @Damian Actually there are some cases where you cannot use the VBA names. Like when you have sheets that are generated at run time. This makes using VBA names for that sheet impossible because you would get compile errors. Then you have to use `Worksheets()`.

Answer (score 1):

`1) When passing a variable from one procedure to another, is it a bad idea to use the same name in both procedures?`

There are 2 ways to pass parameters to another procedure, `ByVal` and `ByRef`.

As per default VBA uses `ByRef` so doing this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To 1000
        Call Tested(i)
    Next i

End Sub
Sub Tested(i As Long)

    i = i + 1

End Sub
```

Would drive you insane because from the first loop, `i = 0` will jump to `i = 2` . Why? Because `Tested()` will add 1 to `i` and the `Next i` in `Test()` another.

How to avoid this and still use the same variable? use `ByVal` so you will give `Tested()` the value of `i` and changes on `Tested()` won't affect your initial loop.

Global variables? You shouldn't use them if possible.

When to use them **on my experience**?

For example, working with a lot of worksheets in a workbook and different procedures which will call them, then just get a sub setting all the worksheet and declare them as global.

Other cases I don't think it's necessary since like QHarr said, for optimization passing parameters to procedures is faster.

Comment: So in my case, I just have one PowrPoint Presentation. Does it make sense to declare `
`Public mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Public PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Public myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation`
globally?

Comment: No, you don't need to do that. You can pass the variables, unless you have multiple procedures working them without any correlation. But if procedure 1 does X and procedure 2 can't be done without X the logic is to pass the parameters from procedure to procedure.